# How can I remove boilerplate when writing overloaded strings?

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

Given the following code:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

newtype Firstname = Firstname String deriving (Eq, Show)
instance IsString Firstname where fromString = Firstname

newtype Lastname = Lastname String deriving (Eq, Show)
instance IsString Lastname where fromString = Lastname

data Person = Person { firstname :: Firstname, lastname :: Lastname, age :: Int } deriving Show
```

I'd like to remove the boilerplate around creating strongly-typed strings. Is is possible to use Template Haskell (or some other means) to achieve this?

eg something like:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, TemplateHaskell #-}

$(strongString ''Firstname)
$(strongString ''Lastname)

data Person = Person { firstname :: Firstname, lastname :: Lastname, age :: Int } deriving Show
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` and derive the `IsString` instance for `Firstname` and `Lastname`. A sample code for your example follows

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
import Data.String

newtype Firstname = Firstname String deriving (Eq, Show, IsString)

newtype Lastname = Lastname String deriving (Eq, Show, IsString)

data Person = Person { firstname :: Firstname
                     , lastname :: Lastname
                     , age :: Int
                     }

foo = Person "hello" "world" 10
```

You can use TH to write a similar function which you want but it is not worth the effort while keeping those functions in a separate module and then importing them here.